# Wait for callback function before the result of another callback function

Tags: javascript, callback, synchronization, web-sql

I have a problem in my method. `elenco_prodotti` must wait the method `sincro.query` to proceed to add the final outputs, but now I see only the empty divs, because it needs to be synchronous.

Please, help me!

```
this.elenco_prodotti = function (callBack) {
    var output = '';

    for (var c = 1; c < 5; c++ /*categoria*/)
    {
        for (var p = 1; p < 5; p++/*pagina*/)
        {
            output += "<div class='pag_" + p + " cat_" + c + "'>";

            var sql = 'SELECT cat_varianti,colore_tasto,id,descrizione,prezzo_1 FROM prodotti WHERE categoria="' + c + '" AND pagina="' + p + '"';

            output += '<div class="bs-docs-section btn_' + comanda.dispositivo + ' "> \n\
            <div class="bs-glyphicons"> \n\
             <ul class="bs-glyphicons-list">';

            for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
                for (var x = 1; x <= 8; x++) {

                    var posizione_attuale = y + "-" + x;
                    var testo_query = sql + ' AND posizione="' + posizione_attuale + '" LIMIT 1;';

                    comanda.sincro.query(testo_query, function (prodotto)
                    {
                        if (prodotto[0] && prodotto[0]['descrizione'].length > 0)
                        {
                            prodotto = prodotto[0];
                            prodotto['descrizione'] = prodotto['descrizione'].replace("'", " ");

                            switch (comanda.dispositivo) {
                                case "COMANDA":
                                    if (prodotto['descrizione']) {
                                        output += '<li style="background-color:' + prodotto['colore_tasto'] + '" onClick="aggiungi_articolo(\'' + prodotto['id'] + '\',\'' + prodotto['descrizione'] + '\',\'' + prodotto['prezzo_1'] + '&euro;\',\'null\',$(\'#quantita_articolo\').val(),\'null\',\'' + prodotto['cat_varianti'] + '\')"> \n\
                                                        <span  class="glyphicon-class">' + prodotto['descrizione'] + '<br/>€ ' + prodotto['prezzo_1'] + '</span> \n\
                                                            </li>';
                                    } else {
                                        output += '<li style="display:table;"> \n\
                                                         <span class="glyphicon" aria-hidden="true"></span> \n\
                                                                <span  class="glyphicon-class"></span> \n\
                                                                    </li>';
                                    }
                                    break;

                                case "LAYOUT TASTI":
                                    output += '<li ';

                                    if (prodotto['colore_tasto']) {
                                        output += 'style="background-color:' + prodotto['colore_tasto'] + '"';
                                    }
                                    output += ' onClick="modifica_articolo(\'' + c + '\',\'' + posizione_attuale + '\',\'' + prodotto['colore_tasto'] + '\');">  \n\
                                                    <span  class="glyphicon-class">' + prodotto['descrizione'] + '</span> \n\
                                                        </li>';

                                    break;

                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                            output += '</ul></div></div>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            prodotto = null;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            output += '</div>';
        }
    }
    callBack(output);
};
```

Comment: What about using a Promise?

Comment: Promises allow chaining multiple asynchronous function executions (which is what you need in this particular case) and a lot more. Read: https://www.promisejs.org/ https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: ok i'm reading, but how can I apply this promises to my case? Because i'm out of the scope.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for multiple asynchronous things to happen.

At the moment, your code will not work because you are [capturing loop variables in a callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) that probably completes after the loops have completed, meaning that you will have unreliable values for `c`,`p`,`x`,`y`.

You could use [Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) to get around this:

```
this.elenco_prodotti = function (callBack) {
    var promises=[];
    for (var c = 1; c < 5; c++ /*categoria*/)
    {
        for (var p = 1; p < 5; p++/*pagina*/)
        {
            var sql = //your sql;
            for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
                for (var x = 1; x <= 8; x++) {

                    var posizione_attuale = y + "-" + x;
                    var testo_query = //more sql;
                    var prom=new Promise(function(resolve,reject)){
                        var loopVars = {c:c,p:p,y:y,x:x};
                        comanda.sincro.query(testo_query, function (prodotto)
                        {
                            resolve({loopVars:loopVars,prodotto:prodotto})
                        });
                        promises.push(prom);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then(function(data){
        //this callback executes only when
        //all promises have completed...
        var output="";
        data.forEach(function(){item}{
            var c=item.loopVars.c;
            var p=item.loopVars.p;
            var x=item.loopVars.x;
            var y= item.loopVars.y;
            var prodotto=item.prodotto;
            //build your output string here
        });
        callBack(output);
    });
};
```

Comment: oh my god! i'm not undestanding!

Comment: Ok, so you need to find a resource that will teach you about Promises. The [article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) I linked to is an excellent guide... If you take your time to follow it through, you'll have a better understanding of what I suggest here. It really is worth your time to understand exactly what a Promise is... They are becoming a very common solution to exactly this kind of problem, and are starting to become *"required knowledge"* for Javascript developers.

Comment: @RiparazioneComputerMestreDa Assuming you are Italian, this looks good: http://www.html.it/articoli/javascript-asincrono-le-promise-e-la-libreria-q/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is good for one query, but i have this?

It doesn't work... I'm not undestanding very good.

```
var FunzioniDB = function () {

this.elenco_prodotti = function (callBack) {
    //$time=microtime(true);

    var output = '';
    var promises = [];

    var promessa = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        //query per vedere tutti gli id di categoria
        comanda.sincro.query('SELECT id FROM categorie WHERE 1 ORDER BY id ASC', function (cat) {
            //console.log(cat.length);

            for (var key in cat) {
                //console.log(cat[key].id);
                //query per vedere l'ultimo numero di pagina
                comanda.sincro.query("SELECT pagina FROM prodotti WHERE pagina NOT NULL AND pagina != '' AND categoria='" + cat[key].id + "' ORDER BY pagina DESC LIMIT 1;", function (pag) {
                    output += "<div class='pag_" + i + " cat_" + cat[key].id + "' style='display:none;'>";
                    //console.log("cat1 - pagine:= " + parseInt(pag[0].pagina));
                    //apre le intestazioni della comanda 
                    //

                    for (var i = 1; i <= (parseInt(pag[0].pagina) + 1) && i <= 4; i++) {

                        output += '<div class="bs-docs-section btn_COMANDA">\n\
                                <div class="bs-glyphicons">\n\
                                    <ul class="bs-glyphicons-list">';

                        for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
                            for (var x = 1; x <= 8; x++) {

                                var posizione_attuale = y + "-" + x;
                                var query_prodotti = 'SELECT cat_varianti,colore_tasto,id,descrizione,prezzo_1 FROM prodotti WHERE categoria="' + cat[0].id + '" AND pagina="' + pag[0].pagina + '" AND posizione="' + posizione_attuale + '" LIMIT 1;';

                                //console.log(query_prodotti);


                                comanda.sincro.query(query_prodotti, function (oggetto) {


                                    //console.log(typeof(oggetto.prodotto[0]));
                                    if (oggetto !== undefined && oggetto[0] !== undefined && oggetto[0]['descrizione'].length > 0)
                                    {
                                        var prodotto = oggetto[0];

                                        //console.log(prodotto);

                                        output += '<li class="btn_comanda" style="background-color:' + prodotto["colore_tasto"] + ';" onClick="aggiungi_articolo("' + prodotto["id"] + '","' + prodotto["descrizione"] + '","' + prodotto["prezzo_1"] + '&euro; ","null",$("#quantita_articolo").val(),"null","' + prodotto["cat_varianti"] + '");"> \n\
                                 <span class="glyphicon-class">' + prodotto['descrizione'] + '<br/>€ ' + prodotto['prezzo_1'] + '</span> \n\
                                 </li>';
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        output += '<li style="display:table;"> \n\
                                 <span class="glyphicon" aria-hidden="true"></span> \n\
                                 <span class="glyphicon-class"></span> \n\
                                 </li>';
                                    }


                                });
                            }
                        }

                        output += '</ul></div></div></div>'; //chiude le intestazioni
                        resolve({output:output});
                        //alla fine deve creare una pagina in piu, ma il massimo è 4 pagine
                    }
                });
            }
            ;
        });
    });
    promises.push(promessa);


    Promise.all(promises).then(function (data) {
        callBack(data[0].output);
        });
   };
 };
```